# How to send "DateTime.Today" as CommandParameter for Button in WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml

I'm trying to send `DateTime.Today` as a `CommandParameter` for `Button` control.

But I'm receiving `DateTime.MinValue`{1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM} within the ViewModel and I receive the same value when I remove the `CommandParameter`.

Here is my Xaml code:

```
<Button AutomationProperties.AutomationId="TodayButton"
        DataContext="{Binding ViewModel}"
        Command="{Binding SelectDateCommand}"
        CommandParameter="{Binding System.DateTime.Today}"
        Cursor="Hand"
        Content="Today"/>
```

how can I send `DateTime.Today` as a `CommandParameter` and receive today's date in the model?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use [`x:Static` markup extension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop-wpf/xaml-services/xstatic-markup-extension)

```
CommandParameter="{Binding Source={x:Static sys:DateTime.Today}}"
```

Also add `xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"` at the top of your xaml file

Comment: why Binding? `CommandParameter="{x:Static sys:DateTime.Today}"`. also it will give wrong date after midnight it view was loaded before midnight